# How to use SemEval or SemCor dataset for word sense disabiguation model?

Tags: nlp, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

I'm trying to use SemEval dataset for word sense disambiguation but it has index not word to find sense
And also does not have idea about how to use SemCor benchmark dataset

I need to know how to use SemEval, SemCor dataset for word sense disambiguation and need to get decent accuracy and also need to know how to use WordNet in NLP?